# Impossible to create / update Business Unit / Team from workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-foundation

Recently noticed that in MS CRM 2011 is impossible to create / update Business Unit or Team from workflow step.

Why it was made and is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly it's by design. You need to create a custom workflow activity to create/update Business Unit and Team entities.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it was made due to the reason. Are you aware, why it was done?

Comment: It seems to me to be more of a developer/customizer task rather than a power user task or something that would form part of a business process.